# Write Python output to file using makefile

Tags: python, makefile, output, file-io

I have a Python program `prog.py`, that I want to run on a file `input`, and then write its output to  `output.txt`.

In the terminal, this works fine if I type:

```
$ python prog.py < input.py > output.txt
```

Now, I would like to have a makefile that does this same thing. How do I do this?

Comment: You could put `python prog.py < input.py > output.txt` inside of a `run.sh` file and call that through your Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

In your makefile simply have:

```
all:
    python prog.py < input.py > output.txt
```